# open cassandra sstables for row count

Tags: multithreading, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am planning to open all sstables for a given cf for row count and tombstones. It is actually ISSTableScanner and as usual it has to scan each and every row in the sstables.

This works fine if you have limited number of sstables for a given cf. But, what if you have 1000's of sstables, this approach is going to performance issue as it has to open each and every sstable and scan.

Is there any best way to open all the sstables for given cf? I am aware of Runnable Interface to use for SSTableReader openAll() method. other than this, is there any best way to achieve this?

Does MapReduce helps on this?.Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
-Suyodha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the number of tombstones, you can get that by summing the counts of the bins in the `estimatedTombstoneDropTime` of the sstable statistics.

If you're looking for which partition/row has most tombstones you can use https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools (perhaps included in C* someday in sstablemetadata command as part of [CASSANDRA-1148](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1148)) and call the "describe" command, it will give you the tombstone leaders. You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools/blob/9159b69573ba367e4fdf3af9acfad7eb800e061f/src/main/java/com/csforge/sstable/CassandraUtils.java#L297) where it's just for single sstable, but calling openall is just a thin wrapper over that really to open them in parallel.

There is also `spcassandra-tombstones` as part of https://github.com/spotify/cassandra-opstools that you can see implementation of [here](https://github.com/spotify/cassandra-opstools/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spotify/cassandra/opstools/CountTombstones.java).